# Install kernel devel in CentOS VM

Tags: centos, kernel, yum, repository, parallels

I was trying to install Parallels tool in the CentOS VM of Mac OS host and get the following error message,

```
An error occurred while installing the following packages:  │         
        │ - kernel-devel-2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.i686                     │         
        │ - dkms                                                      │         
        │                                                             │         
        │ Install these packages manually and start the Parallels     │         
        │ Tools installation again.
```

I try to install the `dkms` and get the error message provided,

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.dhakacom.com
 * extras: mirror.dhakacom.com
 * updates: mirror.dhakacom.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dkms.noarch 0:2.4.0-1.20170926git959bd74.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: elfutils-libelf-devel for package: dkms-2.4.0-1.20170926git959bd74.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package elfutils-libelf-devel.i686 0:0.164-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: elfutils-libelf(x86-32) = 0.164-2.el6 for package: elfutils-libelf-devel-0.164-2.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package elfutils-libelf.i686 0:0.152-1.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: elfutils-libelf(x86-32) = 0.152-1.el6 for package: elfutils-libs-0.152-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: elfutils-libelf(x86-32) = 0.152-1.el6 for package: elfutils-0.152-1.el6.i686
---> Package elfutils-libelf.i686 0:0.164-2.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package elfutils.i686 0:0.152-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package elfutils.i686 0:0.164-2.el6 will be an update
---> Package elfutils-libs.i686 0:0.152-1.el6 will be updated
---> Package elfutils-libs.i686 0:0.164-2.el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.2.3) for package: elfutils-libs-0.164-2.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zlib.i686 0:1.2.3-27.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: zlib = 1.2.3-27.el6 for package: zlib-devel-1.2.3-27.el6.i686
---> Package zlib.i686 0:1.2.3-29.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zlib-devel.i686 0:1.2.3-27.el6 will be updated
---> Package zlib-devel.i686 0:1.2.3-29.el6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                 Arch     Version                          Repository
                                                                           Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 dkms                    noarch   2.4.0-1.20170926git959bd74.el6   epel    78 k
Installing for dependencies:
 elfutils-libelf-devel   i686     0.164-2.el6                      base    32 k
Updating for dependencies:
 elfutils                i686     0.164-2.el6                      base   255 k
 elfutils-libelf         i686     0.164-2.el6                      base   204 k
 elfutils-libs           i686     0.164-2.el6                      base   251 k
 zlib                    i686     1.2.3-29.el6                     base    73 k
 zlib-devel              i686     1.2.3-29.el6                     base    44 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
Upgrade       5 Package(s)

Total download size: 936 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/Packages/d/dkms-2.4.0-1.20170926git959bd74.el6.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
(2/7): elfutils-0.164-2.el6.i686.rpm                     | 255 kB     00:00     
(3/7): elfutils-libelf-0.164-2.el6.i686.rpm              | 204 kB     00:00     
(4/7): elfutils-libelf-devel-0.164-2.el6.i686.rpm        |  32 kB     00:00     
(5/7): elfutils-libs-0.164-2.el6.i686.rpm                | 251 kB     00:00     
(6/7): zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.i686.rpm                        |  73 kB     00:00     
(7/7): zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.i686.rpm                  |  44 kB     00:00     


Error Downloading Packages:
  dkms-2.4.0-1.20170926git959bd74.el6.noarch: failure: Packages/d/dkms-2.4.0-1.20170926git959bd74.el6.noarch.rpm from epel: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Afterwards, I try to install `kernel-devel-2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.i686` with `yum` and get the following error messsage,

```
$ yum install kernel-devel-2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.i686

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.dhakacom.com
 * extras: mirror.dhakacom.com
 * updates: mirror.dhakacom.com
Setting up Install Process
No package kernel-devel-2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.i686 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

To clarify, both of the instances, the installation is unsuccessful. Then, I run,

`$ yum install kernel-headers` and afterward, I can install the `dkms` with previously mentioned command.

Then, I inspect the versions of kernel devels installed in the VM,

```
$ yum list kernel-devel

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.dhakacom.com
 * extras: mirror.dhakacom.com
 * updates: mirror.dhakacom.com
Installed Packages
kernel-devel.i686                  2.6.32-754.2.1.el6                   @updates
```

So how do I install `kernel-devel-2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.i686` in the CentOS machine? I don't have a lot of experience with the Linux, so, please notify me for any mistakes.

Comment: Are you installing the initial Parallels software from the same repos?

Comment: I have parallels installed and was trying to install the `Parallels tool` with the instructions provided on the webpage: https://kb.parallels.com/en/118876 . When I provide the command `./install`, I get the mentioned error

Comment: Anyone be kind enough to explain to me why I get a downvote for the question?